# Converting words to their roots

Tags: text, machine-learning, corpus

Is there an efficient way to convert all variations of words in a corpus (in a language you're not familiar with) to their roots?

In English, for example, this would mean converting `plays`, `played`, and `playing` into `play`; `did`, `does`, `done`, and `doing` into `do`; `birds` into `bird`; and so on.

The idea I have is to iterate through the less frequent words and test whether a substring of this word is one of the more frequent words. I don't think this is good because, first, it would not affect irregular verbs and, second, I'm not sure that it's always the "root" of the word that's going to be more frequent than some other variation. This method might also change some words erroneously that are totally different from the frequent word included in them.

The reason I want to do this is that I'm working on a classification problem and figured I'd get better results if I worked better on my preprocessing step. If you've done anything similar or have an idea, please do share.

Thank you!

Comment: you should look into lemmatization. You can also try stemming. Lemmatization is a usually more complex (involving things like part of speech to find the appropriate lemma), so depending on your use case stemming might be enough (but from the above sounds like lemmas are what you want). Oh and plenty of standard NLP libraries can help with this (checkout stanford nlp core, and nltk)

Comment: @JPC Thank you. Now that I know what this process is actually called I found a lemmatizer specifically for the language I'm working on (basque)!  Though there's still the problem that this tool is not available as source code; it's only available on [this](http://ixa2.si.ehu.es/demo/analisimorf.jsp) webpage. I'm trying to automate the process of getting a word's lemma through `curl`, but I don't know how to get the output from the pop-up window. Could you help me out with this too? (sorry for going off-topic-- thought it'd be a quick question not worth creating  another thread for)